# Tween object's y coordinate to a specific point 0.1 at a time

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a game where a MovieClip's y coordinate changes (my implementation of gravity), and often the character falls through the ground (the y coordinate increases so much that the MovieClip just skips over the coordinate that makes the character stop going down).  To solve this, I thought maybe the character's y coordinate should increase 0.1 at a time until the character reaches a specific point in a while loop.  I tried something like this:

```
var yToGo = char.y + jumpPow; //jumpPow is something that increases that makes the character "fall" when not touching the ground.
while(char.y !== yToGo)
{
    char.y += char.y < yToGo ? 0.1 : -0.1;
    for(i = 0; i < fallingBlocks.length; i++) //fallingBlocks is basically the array that holds "ground"
    {
        if(charTouchingFallingBlock(i)) //checks if the character is touching any of the grounds
        {
            jumping = false; //Makes character stop falling
            char.y = fallingBlocks[i].y; //Makes character go to y of the ground it's touching
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `charTouchingFallingBlock` function checks if the character is touching any ground by taking an integer as one of the parameters, it looks like:

```
function charTouchingFallingBlock(i)
{
    return jumpPow >= 0 && fallingBlocks[i].hitTestPoint(char.x, char.y, true) && char.y <= fallingBlocks[i].y);
}
```

this barely works, as the SWF application freezes sometimes when the character is "falling" and the nearest ground is a little below the character.  As you can see, I basically make the character go towards the y coordinate and stop when it reaches it, or stop when it touches ground (stops character from going through ground).

Is there something wrong with my loop, or is there a library that has a function built-in that can do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the very nature of floating point, it will always be inaccurate. You should first loop through all the blocks, and if a block is in the way, fall on it. Otherwise, just change `char.y` to the `yToGo`.

Fixed code:

```
var yToGo = char.y + jumpPow; // jumpPow is something that increases that makes the character "fall" when not touching the ground.
var fellOnBlock:Boolean = false;
for (i = 0; i < fallingBlocks.length; i++) // fallingBlocks is basically the array that holds "ground"
{
    var block:FallingBlock = fallingBlocks[i]; // I'm just assuming your classname
    if (char.x > block.x && char.x + char.width < block.x && char.y < block.y && yToGo > block.y)
    {
        jumping = false; // Makes character stop falling
        char.y = block.y; // Makes character go to y of the ground it's touching
        fellOnBlock = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!fellOnBlock) char.y = yToGo;
```

`char.x > block.x && char.x + char.width < block.x` makes sure the character is above the FallingBlock, and `char.y < block.y && yToGo > block.y` makes sure the block is in the way. If both checks are true, the character falls onto the block.